# How to use fontawesome in ionic 2 rc0?

Tags: ionic2

How to use `fontawesome` in `ionic 2 rc0` as there is no `gulp/grunt` file so I can add file into build process?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article i came across while searching on this same topic.

https://chriztalk.com/ionic-2-font-awesome-using-sass/

Here's a gist:

1. **Make a new config directory the root of your ionic 2 project:**

   ```
   $ mkdir config
   ```
2. **Find the `copy.config.js` and `sass.config.js` files into this folder: `/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/` and copy them into the folder you just created.**
3. **Add these lines to the new `copy.config.js` in `config` directory you just created.**

   ```
   ...
   copyFontAwesomeCSS: {
     src: '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
     dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css/'
   },
   copyFontAwesome: {
     src: '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*',
     dest: '{{WWW}}/fonts/'
   },
   ...
   ```
4. **Add these lines to the  `includePaths[]` block of the `sass.config.js` file in the `config` directory you just created:**

   ```
   ...
   includePaths: [
     ...
     'node_modules/font-awesome/scss',
     ...
   ],
   ...
   ```
5. **Add a config block in your `package.json` file with the following references:**

   ```
   ...
   "config": {
     "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js",
     "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
   },
   ....
   ```
6. **Import font-awesome in your `app.scss` file:**

   ```
   ...
   @import 'font-awesome';
   ...
   ```
7. **Finally, use font awesome like you would in any html file:**

   ```
   <h1><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Font Awesome</h1>
   ```

Comment: I don't particularily like this method as if the core Copy script (/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/) changes you will not get those changes in your script. I would prefer to fix the version of FA and copy it manually once from NodeModules into the Assets folder and upgrade it manually when I want

Answer (score 2):

There is still a lot of confusion on what is a best practice when it comes to adding FontAwesome to an ionic2 app, so I wrote an article about it to mitigate some of that confusion. I hope this helps anybody else looking for a correct answer
http://luiscabrera.site/tech/2017/01/09/fontawesome-in-ionic2.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply add cdn css link of font awesome to your index.html

Or you can use @import of sass to add it to your project

```
@import 'lib/fa.css'
```

Comment: I don't want to add additional `css/js` file. I want to include it into the build process that will automatically merge it into `main.css` file